# How to Call a slot of another class without creating its object?

Tags: qt

I have two classes A and B.  I want to call a slot of class A in B without Creating the object of class A. Is this possible?
I've tried this in class B
connect (PButton, SIGNAL(triggered()) , A , SLOT(slotofA));
but I'm getting an error "expected primary expression befor ',' "

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to accomplish this task.

- You can make slot a static function that way you can call it with class name dot function name.
- Make class A singleton and than you can access all of its public functions without creating a object.

Hope it will help !